# How to print one time in for loop

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I am coding a program to find the Prime Number project for my school. I used function and for loop to do this project. My problem is my print statement is not working correctly. I want to print if it's prime or not just for one time. I know why it's repeating (bcz of for loop) but I want to know how to print one time.

Ps

```
my else:
    print ("not prime")
```

it is not working, i don't why... If anyone help me that will be great. Here is my code:

---

```
def printscrean(m):
    if m > 0:
        print ("YES! It is a Prime Number \n")
        print (ASK, "MOD", i , "=", m)
    else:
        print ("not prime")
        return;

ASK = int (input("YOUR NUMBER:")) 

for i in range (2,ASK): 
    m= ASK%i 
    if (m == 0): 
        break
    printscrean(m)
```

Comment: Just put the `printscrean(m)` call _outside_ the `for` loop.

Comment: what do you think about the break ? it occurs with the same condition as in your function

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have the correct logic? 
1. You should check if the number is greater than 1 or not. 
2. I'd prefer to do all the work inside the function (cleaner code :) )
3. Your problem was in the placement of the print statment inside the loop

```
#3 
def printscrean(num): 
    flag = 0 
    for i in range (2, num): 
        if (num % i == 0): 
            print ("Not prime")
            flag =1 
            break
    if flag == 0 :
        print ("YES! It is a Prime Number \n")


#1
ASK = int (input("YOUR NUMBER:")) 
if ASK > 1: 
   #2 
   printscrean(ASK)
else: 
   print("The number is not prime")
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: there you go  :)